# SFML Threads error

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I'm trying to make a threaded application using SFML and when creating a thread i have come across this error.

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

This is my code and what it basically does is setup the networking listening and accepting and what i'm trying to achieve is a networking thread that i can run through the `main`.

```
#include "Networking.h"

Networking::Networking(void)
{
    sf::Thread thread(&Networking::TCPSocket, 1000);
    thread.launch();
}

Networking::~Networking(void)
{
    SetNetworking(false);
}

void Networking::TCPSocket(int port)
{
    InitNetworking();

    sf::TcpSocket client;
    sf::TcpListener listener;

    // bind the listener to a port
    if (listener.listen(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        Logger::Wrn("Could not bind to port:", port);
    } else {
        Logger::Log("Successfully bound to port:", port);
    }

    Logger::Log("Ready to receive connections");
    while(IsNeworkRunning() == true)
    {
        if(listener.accept(client) == sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            Logger::Log("New connection received from");
        } else {
            Logger::Wrn("Connection from", client.getRemoteAddress(), "could not connect");
        }
    }
}

void Networking::SetNetworking(bool i)
{
    i = this->_networkStarted;
}

bool Networking::IsNeworkRunning()
{
    if(_networkStarted == false)
    {
        Logger::Err("Failed to initialise the networking");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else {
        return _networkStarted;
    }
}

void Networking::InitNetworking()
{
    SetNetworking(true);
    Logger::Log("Network initialised");
}
```

That is the .cpp where the error is coming from if you need the header i can post it but i'm not sure you will.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When invoking a pointer to a member function, you need to a pointer to the object it will be called on, as well.

Comment: But if i am doing that then how do i add the function arguments

Comment: Pass in a bound function, created via `std::bind` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Non-static Member functions (ones that belong to a class) have a hidden argument -- a pointer to an instance of the class.  Let's look at your class for an example:

```
Networking foo;
foo.TCPSocket(1000);
```

While it doesn't *look* like there are two arguments, there is a hidden one implicitly: the pointer to the object `foo`.  In C-style OOP code, the same thing might be accomplished by having by a function take a pointer to the object plus any arguments, so you would write:

```
CStyleTCPSocket(&foo, 1000);
```

In C++, things work similarly under the hood, but there is some syntax sugar to make things look maybe a little prettier.  The call:

```
foo.TCPSocket(1000);
```

Gets turned into:

```
Networking::TCPSocket(&foo, 1000); //not legal code, it's just to make a point
```

So how can you fix your problem?  When you start the thread like this:

```
std::thread someThread(&Networking::TCPSocket, 1000);
```

The compiler is looking at TCPSocket and thinking "wait, I need two arguments, the pointer to the object *and* the integer!"  And what's the pointer to the object when you're *in* the object like you are here?  The `this` keyword.  Tying it all together:

```
std::thread someThread(&Networking::TCPSocket, this, 1000);
```

This should do the trick!

**EDIT:**

`sf::Thread` does not support more than one argument as it as naive implementation for use with compilers that do not support C++11 [Source](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-thread.php).  `std::thread` from the C++11 STL header ` will properly handle multiple arguments.

Comment: Ah, my fault, I thought `sf::Thread` was an early stop-gap for `std::thread`.  What compiler are you using?  If it supports `std::thread` it would fix all your problems.  SFML actually suggests that you use `std::thread` if possible as their own is worse in many ways: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/system-thread.php

Comment: I'm using visual studios

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, you can `#include <thread>` and use `std::thread` instead of `sf::Thread` which is a much better multi-threading class and supports the code in my answer.